# why i can't do Web scraping python bs4 in steam market price skins

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I don't understand, I'm trying to take data from the steam community market for the price of the skin and I get a quote at the place where the price is located (Please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs44
import requests

url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Hyper%20Beast%20%28Well-Worn%29"
info = requests.get(url)

soup = bs44(info.content, "html.parser")
name = soup.find(id='market_buyorder_info').find(id='market_commodity_buyrequests')
print(name)
```

Comment: Show us an example of the html, and show us what the program prints.

Answer (score 2):

This particular website is a real time web app. When you open the page javascript fires up in the background and keeps requesting sale details every few seconds and updates the page.

If you developer tools of your browser (usually F12 key) and click network tab you'll see these requests are being made:

[image]

To url: https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=US&language=english&currency=1&item_nameid=49399562&two_factor=0

If you click on it you'll see it returns sale information in json format.
All you have to do in your web-scraper is request this url instead of the one you're requesting. Most important parameter here seems to be `item_nameid` which is ID of the sold item - you can find it in the html of your original url:

[image]

You can use regex to search html body for it:

```
re.findall(r"Market_LoadOrderSpread\( (\d+) \)", html)
```

Comment: And what if I need to automate this, I need to insert a link to the skin https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29 - for example, and how to get a json link in the code

Comment: @КонстантинЛенивков if you only know the html url then you can find item ID in the page source. See my answer edit.